# Why does the following equality hold?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded open subset and $f(x) \in C_0^\infty(U)$. Why does the following equality hold for $1<k$, $0<l$ (assuming the integral is well-defined)?
$$
\int_{U}\frac{f(x)^{k-1}}{x^l}x\cdot \nabla f dx=\frac{n-l}{k}\int_{U}\frac{f(x)^k}{x^l}dx
$$

I think this is a standard vector calculus identity, but I don't see how things work. I relly appreciate your help.